# Dojo Internet Explorer 6 png problem

Tags: javascript, css, image, dojo, png

Everything works fine in all browsers excluding Internet Explorer 6. `png` images shows white background behind them. How to get rid of them in **Dojo**. I am using dojo version 1.5.

Comment: by "in Dojo" do you mean a particular image in the Dojo distro which requires a CSS fix to look right on IE6, or some more general mechanism?  Dojo and Dijit have gifs and CSS to make things look right in IE6, IIRC

Comment: There are some round corner images in my application. They are in png. What do you suggest me to do. IePngFix or any other solution.

Comment: IE6 does not handle PNG's correctly.  You'll need to use the "*" and "_" trick to point your image to a GIF image when the browser is IE6 -- with CSS.  In Dojo, you can check the dojo.isIE property and if it is 6, then you can replace the URL's of your PNG images with GIF's.

Comment: or try the alpha trick below, I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE6 doesn't support PNG transparency properly. It has several known bugs.

There are hacks to get around it - try [IEPNGFix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/), but there are several other variants of the hack available.

Comment: I know these fixes but I want one using Dojo.

Comment: @imran: why do you want to use Dojo? Those fixes use hardly any JS at all (except for the BG-repeat fix).

Comment: I am using dojo all over my application for other tasks. Thats why I want this fix also in dojo.

Comment: @imran - you didn't specify in the question that you would only accept an answer that uses Dojo. You also didn't state that you know about the other fixes. Anyway, I don't know whether anyone has written a Dojo-specific version of this fix. I don't suppose it would be difficult. But I can't see why anyone would bother, given that the existing solutions are so simple to use without needing any libraries.

Comment: @Spudley: I mentioned that I want in dojo :) If I did not find fix in dojo then I would need to alter images or use some other method like one you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try add alfa filter on it? Like this:

```
style="background:url('/upload/contents/371/dish-main2.png ');
background: expression('none');
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=/upload/contents/371/dish-main2.png, sizingMethod=crop);
```

Can help you with IE6.

Comment: Looks good, but how can I use it in <img src="images/dialog/add.png" alt="Add"/> ;as there is no background image.

Comment: Oh, sorry. This is code for the empty transparent gif: http://ambar.rosinter.ru/upload/images/d-t.gif (this is done for the simple protect of image stealing). Unfortunately, I can't make this code without such hack.